# Vagrant up is not launching my VM on windows

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, chef-solo, vagrant-windows

I have an issue when launching vagrant in Windows. I'm using a modified version of Vagrant and Chef for Proxy reasons, I have this error:

```
==> default: Booting VM... 
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes... 
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222 
default: SSH username: vagrant 
default: SSH auth method: private key 
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying... 
==> default: Machine booted and ready!  
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM... 
==> default: Checking for host entries C:/Utilisateurs/A/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/daemons-1.2.3/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:10‌​:in `fork': fork() function is unimp
```

Can anyone help me?

    Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know if it's a SSH keys problem?

Comment: I think it can be windows firewall, is there an exception for port 2222?

Comment: Thanks @jjung, do you have any idea how to solve this issue please?